# How to cross compile FreeRDP for ARM

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, embedded-linux, freerdp

In the wiki of FreeRDP on GitHub, I don't find any instrument to tell me how to  cross compile FreeRDP for ARM. Is anyone who succeed in cross-compiling FreeRDP? I compile this in ubuntu 15 for desktop withing arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc. and compile zlib, openssl, glib with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc too; but when I make the FreeRDP, it has many errors.

Does anyone know how to do this?

the cmake command is
cmake -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Linux" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/yousy/freerdp-arm/" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib" -DWITH_SSE2=OFF -DWITH_SSE2_TARGET=OFF  -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/" -DLIB_EAY="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libcrypto.a" -DSSL_EAY="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libssl.a" -DGlib_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/local/glib/glib-2.45/" -DGlibConfig_INCLUDE_DIR="/usr/local/glib/glib-2.45/" -DGlib_LIBRARY="/usr/local/glib/glib-2.45/" -DGobject_LIBRARY="/usr/local/glib/glib-2.45/"

and when I make , it take error, shown in the picture
[image]

Comment: I use the github source,the FreeRDP version is 2.0.0

Comment: What are the command lines used for cross compiling freeRDP? How do you invoke CMake for example?